# How to generate sql script by reading the data from an excel sheet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel

Currently i am working on c# .net and i need to generate scripts ( sql insert scripts ) by using the data that is present in an excel sheet.

**To be more specific,**

> If the excel sheet has three columns with

```
**column name** ColumName1, ColumName2, ColumName3 
**data like**   Value1,     Value2,     Value3
```

i need to write code to generate the insert script like -

> INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([ColumName1], [ColumName2], [ColumName3])
>   VALUES ('Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3')

Any ideas ?

Comment: do you want to create script in the excel sheet or some where else?

Comment: @krshekhar I just need the scripts to be generated. I must be able to run the scripts in my database (sql server). So its not a problem where it can be generated. I just need the scripts. You can do it your own way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to write a forumla for the final column for instance:

```
="insert into tblyourtablename (intmine, strval) values ("&B4&", N'"&C4&"'); set @intpane = scope_identity(); INSERT INTO tblpane (nameid_fk,strtext,bitmine,vbarmine) VALUES (@intpane ,N'"&D8&"' ,0 ,convert(varbinary,''));"
```

This should get your started

**EDIT**

Why do some SQL strings have an 'N' prefix?
You may have seen Transact-SQL code that passes strings around using an N prefix. This denotes that the subsequent string is in Unicode (the N actually stands for National language character set). Which means that you are passing an NCHAR, NVARCHAR or NTEXT value, as opposed to CHAR, VARCHAR or TEXT. See Article #2354 for a comparison of these data types.

For further reading please view the following link

http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-some-sql-strings-have-an-n-prefix.html

Comment: Thank you for the response. I need to know what does N' exactly mean and what is it's operation here ?

Comment: Please see me edit for the explaination for having an N, I do not know your column datatypes but N is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It has the relevant information. And also i found this article that is really giving a best piece of understanding about our N' discussion.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239530

'N - Its for Unicode data and stands for National language character set as you said. But it is not a mandatory one and  depends on our requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myConnection = new OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\\Language_Batch1_OneClick.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"); ;
var myCommand = new OleDbCommand();
var upCommand = new OleDbCommand();
int i = 0;
try
{

    string sql = null;
    string Value1 =null;
    string Value2=null;
    string Value3=null;
    myConnection.Open();
    myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
    sql = "select ColumName1,ColumName1from,ColumName3  [sheet-name]";
    myCommand.CommandText = sql;
    var dataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
    {
      value1=dataReader["ColumName1"].ToString();
      value2=dataReader["ColumName2"].ToString();
      value3=dataReader["ColumName3"].ToString();

    string newQuery="INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([ColumName1], [ColumName2], [ColumName3]) VALUES ('"+Value1+"', '"+Value2+"', '"+Value3+"')"
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding and for the explanation.

Comment: you are welcome and please marked the answer it it helped you to solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Read excel and get data ,then generate insert script